# JavaScript/HTML - Add up the values from dropdown list and textbox

Tags: javascript, html

just want to ask that how to extract the values from dropdown list and from textbox, then total up them together and display the total? I googled around and tried different ways but it did not worked.
Still learning in HTML and JavaScript.

```html
What is your height? (centimetres)
<select>
  <option name="height1" value="100">100cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="101">101cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="102">102cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="103">103cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="104">104cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="105">105cm</option>
</select>
<br><br> What is your weight? (kg)
<input type="number" id="weight1" step="0.01" name="weight" pattern="\d{4}" autocomplete="off"><br><br> BMI: <input type="text" id="txtresult" name="bmi" readonly>
<input type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate_bmi()">
```

```js
function calculate_bmi()
{
 /*var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("height1").value);
 var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight1").value);
 if ((h != parseFloat(h, 10)) || (w != parseFloat(w, 10)))
  alert("Must insert number")
 if ( ( h <= 0 ) || ( w <= 0 ) )
  alert("Please insert positive numbers")
 if ( ( h >= 2.7 ) || ( w >= 500 ) )
  alert("Out of range");
 else
 {
  var result = w / h / h;
  result = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
  document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
 }*/
 var h = document.getElementsByName("height1");
 //h = h / 100;
 var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight1").value);
 var result = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++)
 {
  if(h[i].tagName == 'SELECT')
  {
   //result = w / Number(h[i].options[h[i].selectedIndex].value);
   result = h + w;
  }
  if (h[i].checked)
  {
   //result = parseFloat(h[i].value);
   result = h + w;
  }
 }
 document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result.toFixed(2);
}
```

And I follows some solutions that available in Internet but it cannot works. The textbox values worked (commented code) but I want to use dropdown list and textbox to sum up together but I failed.
Note: Just want to sum up things together. Because I want to know how to get and add the values inside the dropdown list and textbox. Then I will do the rest of them (calculating BMI).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value from the dropdown/select element, you can use:

`document.querySelector('select').value;`

This will give you a string (words), however, since you want to do calculations with this input you need it to be a number (integer, float etc...) so we can use a `+` in front of this statement to convert it to a number:

`+document.querySelector('select').value;`

However, I recommend that you add an `id` to your `select` element so you can target it like so (adding an id will improve your code's runtime):

`+document.getElementById('height').value;`

To get the value from your textbox, you can do:

`+document.getElementById('weight1').value;`

Here we are also converting it to a number by using the `+` operator.

Lastly, to set the `bmi`'s textbox to the calculated value you can use:

`document.getElementById("txtresult").value = bmi;`

See working example below:

```js
function calculate_bmi() {
  let height = +document.getElementById("height").value;
  let weight = +document.getElementById("weight1").value;
  let bmi = height + weight; // perform bmi calculation here
  document.getElementById("txtresult").value = bmi;
}
```

```html
What is your height? (centimetres)
<select id="height">
  <option name="height1" value="100">100cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="101">101cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="102">102cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="103">103cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="104">104cm</option>
  <option name="height1" value="105">105cm</option>
</select>
<br><br> What is your weight? (kg)
<input type="number" id="weight1" step="0.01" name="weight" pattern="\d{4}" autocomplete="off"><br><br> BMI: <input type="text" id="txtresult" name="bmi" readonly>
<input type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate_bmi()">
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. It really helps me a lot in order to understand the codes. Really appreciate it ^^

Comment: @Desmond97 No worries, glad to help:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.getElementsByName("height1")[0]` to get the desired element, then use `h.options[h.selectedIndex].value` to find the selected value. Then, you can use `parseFloat` as usual:

```js
function calculate_bmi() {
  var h = document.getElementsByName("height1")[0];
  h = parseFloat(h.options[h.selectedIndex].value);
  // h = h / 100;
  var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight1").value);
  console.log(h, w);
  var result = h + w;
  document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
What is your height? (centimetres)
<select name="height1">
  <option value="100">100cm</option>
  <option value="101">101cm</option>
  <option value="102">102cm</option>
  <option value="103">103cm</option>
  <option value="104">104cm</option>
  <option value="105">105cm</option>
</select>
<br><br> What is your weight? (kg)
<input type="number" id="weight1" step="0.01" name="weight" pattern="\d{4}" autocomplete="off"><br><br> BMI: <input type="text" id="txtresult" name="bmi" readonly>
<input type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate_bmi()">
```

As a side note, `name` should be added to the control (i.e. the `<select>` element) and not the values inside it (i.e. the `<option>` elements).

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. I modified your html a bit and added an id to the select box.

```js
  function calculate_bmi() {
          /*var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("height1").value);
     var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight1").value);
     if ((h != parseFloat(h, 10)) || (w != parseFloat(w, 10)))
      alert("Must insert number")
     if ( ( h <= 0 ) || ( w <= 0 ) )
      alert("Please insert positive numbers")
     if ( ( h >= 2.7 ) || ( w >= 500 ) )
      alert("Out of range");
     else
     {
      var result = w / h / h;
      result = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
      document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
     }*/
          var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
          var h = parseFloat(selectBox.value);
          //h = h / 100;
          var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight1").value);
          var result = h+w;
          document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result.toFixed(2);
        }
```

```html
 <html>
      <body>
        What is your height? (centimetres)
        <select id="selectBox">
          <option name="height1" value="100">100cm</option>
          <option name="height1" value="101">101cm</option>
          <option name="height1" value="102">102cm</option>
          <option name="height1" value="103">103cm</option>
          <option name="height1" value="104">104cm</option>
          <option name="height1" value="105">105cm</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        What is your weight? (kg)
        <input
          type="number"
          id="weight1"
          step="0.01"
          name="weight"
          pattern="\d{4}"
          autocomplete="off"
        /><br /><br />
        BMI: <input type="text" id="txtresult" name="bmi" readonly />
        <input
          type="button"
          name="calculate"
          value="Calculate"
          onclick="calculate_bmi()"
        />
      </body>
      <script>
      
      </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the value from the dropdown list.
Get the Select element by name which stores it as an array, then run a for loop through the list and extract the value. See below,

```
function calculate_bmi() {
    var value = 0;
    var h = document.getElementsByName("height1");
    for(var i = 0; i<h.length; i++){
        if(h[i].selected){
            value = h[i].value
            // Do something with the value
        }
    }
}
```